# Articulate Chatbot Installation "ERROR: for rasa Cannot start service rasa: OCI runtime create failed"

Tags: chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, articulate

After installing docker toolbox and rasa to run articulate chatbot, After trying docker-compose up and configuring docker-compose.yml file, I receive this error.

Please help.[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKirT.png)

Comment: please include your docker-compose or any other docker files which are being used in your up process.

Comment: I've answered below, but agree with @parisssss that your question should include a little bit more detail. Also, if you could include the full error message directly without using a screenshot it will help others find this issue by searching for the error.

Answer (score 2):

One of the developers behind Articulate here. Sorry that you had trouble getting it started. I believe the error that you are presenting is a known hurdle when mounting drives on Windows. There is more discussion [here](https://github.com/codekitchen/dinghy/issues/241#issuecomment-328940183). Here are a few potential solutions you should try:

From that article the suggested fix is to:

> I went to docker settings -> Shared Drives . There I Reset my credentials, applied, unchecked my shared drives, applied, rechecked, apply, re-entered my credentials somewhere along the line, and eventually restarted my PC. Some of these steps may not be necessary, but this was the area that fixed it for me. :)

Second, try to [convert the paths](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_convert_windows_paths) to be windows friendly:

> Enable path conversion from Windows-style to Unix-style in volume definitions. Users of Docker Machine and Docker Toolbox on Windows should always set this. Defaults to 0. Supported values: true or 1 to enable, false or 0 to disable.

[Here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4303#issuecomment-379563170)'s a good breakdown of how to do this:

> 1. On Command Line: "set COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1";
> 2. Restart Docker for Windows;
> 3. Go to Docker for Windows settings > Shared Drives > Reset credentials > select drive > Apply;
> 4. Reopen Command Line;
> 5. Kill the Containers;
> 6. Rerun the Containers.

Another possible solution would be to run on a linux VM where the file system is less likely to cause problems.

If all of that fails, please contact us on our [Gitter](https://github.com/samtecspg/articulate), [create an issue](https://github.com/samtecspg/articulate/issues/new), or [e-mail me](https://github.com/wrathagom). We can troubleshoot more directly and also offer a hosted trial for you to play with.